# Can't set attribute of document.documentElement;

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have following code to set the dark mode for the `document.body`

```js
function myFunction() {
  var element = document.body;
  element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
}
```

```css
.dark-mode {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
  <input onclick="myFunction()" type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

If I set the `document.body` to `document.documentElement` it does not work. Does someone know how to fix it for the root element of the HTML? I also tried `document.querySelector(":root");`.

Comment: what do you mean? You not trying to set attribtues, you trying to apply a class which works just fine.

Comment: [What do you mean "It doesn't work"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147616/what-do-you-mean-it-doesnt-work) . Give a proper description of the error or unexpected behaviour you receive.

Comment: [`document.documentElement` works perfectly well](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/znqtc259/), what problem have you experienced?

Comment: `var element = document.documentElement.querySelector("body");` Is this what you want?

Comment: no guys, I can set the attribut of the body to a new color. But can't set the whole html to the color. So the question: how can I set the whole html to a new css attribute? I thought it works with document.documentElement but It does not work....

Answer (score 0):

So the code as you have it seem to be working fine, both `document.body` and `document.documentElement`, so the issue might be related on where and how you are importing de CSS.

With `document.documentElement`

```html
<style>
    .dark-mode {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
</style>
<label for="toggle" class="switch">
    Toggle
    <input onclick="myFunction()" type="checkbox">
    <span class="slider round"></span>
  </label>
  
  
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var element = document.documentElement;
      element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
    }
  </script>
```

With `document.body`

```html
<style>
    .dark-mode {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
</style>
<label class="switch">
    Toggle
    <input onclick="myFunction()" type="checkbox">
    <span class="slider round"></span>
  </label>
  
  
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var element = document.body;
      element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
    }
  </script>
```

But also as a general recommendation de input shouldn't be wrapped in the label tag.

```html
<style>
    .dark-mode {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
</style>
<label for="toggle" class="switch">
    Toggle
  </label>
  <input id="toggle" name="toggle" onclick="myFunction()" type="checkbox">
    <span class="slider round"></span>
  
  
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var element = document.body;
      element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. yes I have this also tried, but didn't work.

Comment: this is where I want to try it: https://markb.de/

Comment: You got a fixed background color for the top part of the site, more specifically in #cover: {
 background: var(--actual-background-color) url(/assets/cover.png); }